# Jquery, Ajax, PHP and Mysql function returns data in HTML code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

As above I am using a function to search a MySql database and display the results in a designated table but the return information is being displayed in HTML code instead (as below)

```
<style type="text/css">
.style39 {font-family: Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
.style92 {font-size: 12px}
</style>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr class="PartListHeader">
```

My JavaScript:

```
$('input#PartNumber_Submit').on('click', function() {
    var PartNumber = $('input#PartNumber').val();
    if ($.trim(PartNumber) != ''){
        $.post('small-displays/PartSearchResults.php', {PartNumber: PartNumber}, function(data) {
            $('div#name-data').text(data);
        });
    }
});
```

I've been tinkering with the data . text but I'm well and truely lost and my mind has even lost with what to do. 1 hour and 50 minutes starring at the same small script! ARGH!

Something simple no doubt!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `.text()` which takes the passed in argument and places it into a text node within the specified element. If it's html, it won't render as html - you'll get the raw html source code. You want `.html()` instead:

```
        $('div#name-data').html(data);
                           ^^^^
```

Comment: Ahhhhhh!  You've just released a stress valve from my head!

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $('div#name-data').html(data);
```

instead of this statement

```
$('div#name-data').text(data);
```